# Javascript Replacement With Object Destructuring

Tags: javascript, replace, destructuring

I have a variable like below:

```
var temp = 'Hello world {variable1}. It is just a {variable2}';
```

And I have a object like below:

```
var object = {variable1: 12, variable2: 15, variable3: 20 ...};
```

As a result, I want to replace temp data with object variables. temp.replace(object...)

It can be solved by

```
Object.keys(object).forEach(o => temp.replace(o, object[o]));
```

Is there a more practical way?

Comment: Can you change the value of temp? Or is it mandatory to have this specific format?

Comment: Is your variable temp going to always have a dynamic number of `variables`, or are you just trying to get all the values in the object?

Comment: This has nothing to do with destructuring?!

Comment: I think OP is asking if it's possible to use destructuring here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a function for replacement and hand over the key for getting the value.

```js
var temp = 'Hello world {variable1}. It is just a {variable2}',
    object = { variable1: 12, variable2: 15, variable3: 20 },
    rendered = temp.replace(/\{([^\}]+)\}/g, (_, k) => object[k]);

console.log(rendered);
```

Comment: Thanks Nina for your answer. This can be used. But I wonder something in here. Actually, I store temp data with formatted like ---'Hello world {variable1}. It is just a {variable2}'---. Then I parse it with replacement function. Do you have any suggestion about storing template to parse it easier?

Comment: it is fine, maybe you add a default value for unknown properties, like `object[k] || ''`.

Answer (score 1):

`String.prototype.replace` can replace matches with a function. You could replace all `{...}` with this for example:

```
temp.replace(/\{([^}]+)\}/g, (_, match) => object[match]);
```

You might want to match on character classes only, to not allow `{ with spaces or *strange* things_here! }` (but JS could allow any kind of string)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on if your variable temp going to always have a dynamic number of `variables` and if you are trying to just get all the values in the object.

You can do something like this using destructuring and string literals if you know what exactly is in `object`

```
const {variable1, variable2, variable3} = object
```

```
var temp = `Hello world ${variable1}. It is just a ${variable2}.`

console.log(temp) \\ "Hello world 12. It is just a 15"
```

Comment: Thanks Sherman but this is not my answer.  First of all, I store temp data. Then take back and parse it. So this is not a log data.